# always set same css despite of change from other jquery script

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have a table of around 40columns and many rows. I am using dataTables features like colvis, datatools etc. But after using some feature the table width gets changed as follows

## original

```
<div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px none; width: 100%;">
<div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 500px;">
<div class="dataTables_scrollFoot" style="overflow: hidden; border: 0px none; width: 100%;">
```

## changed

```
<div class="dataTables_scrollHead" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px none; width: 5483px;">
<div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="overflow: auto; width: 5483px; height: 500px;">
<div class="dataTables_scrollFoot" style="overflow: hidden; border: 0px none; width: 5483px;">
```

here the width changes from 100% to 5483px, how can I force width to be 100% all the time

Comment: you can write your own javascript to overwrite over that, but probably you are better of editing the main js.

Comment: Is `5483px` the full width of the parent element?

Comment: @David, No, actually the columns fits in a page(default 100%), but after doing some jQuery manipulations, the width changes to 5483px which is the full width, but again after another jQuery manipulation, the width toggles back to 100%....
Weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS style declaration with the `!important` specification:

```
.dataTables_scrollBody { width: 100% !important; }
```

In general, `!important` is usually discouraged, but to answer "how can I force", that's the way to go.